# Jebediah​​​ (?)

Tags: words, names, hebrew

[Some](https://www.google.ca/webhp?q=jebediah+name&safe=off#q=jebediah+name&safe=off) claim that Jebediah is a Hebrew name.

Is it a Jewish name?

Either way; what does/would it mean, and how is it/would it be spelled and pronounced in Hebrew?

Comment: I can't demonstrate it dispositively, but I'm pretty sure that "Jebediah" is just a corruption of "Jedediah" (with two 'd's), which is an Anglicization of the Hebrew name "ידידיה."

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "some"?

Comment: @DoubleAA​​ OK?

Comment: Could it be some corruption of Ovadiah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at several baby naming websites, you will find that [Isaac is correct](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40771/jebediah#comment108260_40771).  The meaning given to the English name Jebediah is given as "Friend of the Lord," or in Hebrew ידיד י-ה.

Even the sites that do not source it as a variant of Jedediah explain its meaning this way - see [here](http://nameberry.com/babyname/Jebediah).

Regarding Jebediah being its own term, Malbim [does not have](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32825&st=&pgnum=307) such a word as יבד, nor does the Etymological Dictionary based on R' Hirsch (sorry, I don't see an online copy that goes that far into the book).  The word [does not appear in Tanach](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=003922636974222575695%3Adxq675sw--g&ie=windows-1255&q=%E9%E1%E3&hq=inurl%3A%2Fi%2Ft%2F&sa=%20%E7%F4%F9%21%20#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%D7%99%D7%91%D7%93&gsc.page=1), although I only checked for the three letter shoresh.  Thus, "Jebediah" appears to not be a Jewish name.

Comment: @NBZ see edit.  לא ראינו אינו ראיה but those are pretty solid indicators, I think.

Comment: Related: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/8461